# range slider CSS issue in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a range slider for my site which needs to look same on all browser. I am having issue with IE and Edge now.

Issues facing with IE and Edge are:

1. Round slider thumb and hand pointer are not working.

   border-radius:50%;
    cursor: pointer;
2. IE adding a dividing line in slider track and border
   [image]

Here is my code. I would like to know how to fix the issues.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="range"]').on('input change', function() {

    var val = ($(this).val() - $(this).attr('min')) / ($(this).attr('max') - $(this).attr('min'));

    $(this).css('background-image',
      '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, ' +
      'color-stop(' + val + ', orange), ' +
      'color-stop(' + val + ', #C5C5C5)' +
      ')'
    );
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-apperance: none;
  outline: none !important;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.15, orange), color-stop(0.15, #C5C5C5));
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 100ms;
}

input[type='range']:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/*Firefox */

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="range"]:hover::-moz-range-thumb {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  background: none;
}


/*IE and Edge */

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: hand;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background-color: #C5C5C5;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background-color: orange;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-range-track {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="15">
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/anoopcr/ssbx0anj/28/

Comment: For the lack of a thumb, see [::-ms-thumb appears behind track in MS Edge](//stackoverflow.com/q/40630547)

Comment: in IE I see exactly what you posted in the picture and I can slide the little rectangle and the tooltip appears on top as, I guess, it's supposed to. now in FF I'm only seeing the circle slider and nothing else, no bar, no tooltip, nothing. could you tell me if you fixed this, also could you explain *IE adding a dividing line in slider track and border*